# android check box and radio group on custom dialog

Tags: android, checkbox

Hi I have written simple custom  dialog . which has few check boxs  and one submitt button .

whenever I tried to read the checkbox apllication throws Nullpointer exception .. can somebody helps to solve this , below is my custom dailog  code

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialog.setTitle("Title...");
             CheckBox chk1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkbox1);
               Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   if(chk1.isChecked())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NullPointerException` because you didn't instantiated with `dialog.findViewById()` and set `OnClickListener` for the CheckBox. Place it as below:

```
 CheckBox chk1= (CheckBox)dialog.findViewById(R.id.chkbox1);
 chk1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   //do something here
  });
```

Comment: I am trying add radio group to the custom dialog .. It comes when dialog is loaded , but how to add the action lister to that radio group in the dialog  .. below is my custom layout xml .

Comment: ok. No Problem. Add the Radiogroup as `RadioGroup radGroup = (Radiogroup)dialog.findViewById(R.layout.<yourRadioGroup>)`...

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
CheckBox chk1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkbox1);
```

to:

```
CheckBox chk1= (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.chkbox1);
```

Remember that if you're simply using `findViewById()`, you're calling it for `Activity` in which you currently are, but as far as I see, you want to find this `CheckBox` in `R.layout.custom` which is set for `dialog`.

I see that you're properly loading `dialogButton`, so you probably just forgot to do the same with `chk1`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have populated a layout for dialog then you need to access it through dialog. But you are accessing it through parent view. Anyway just call it through `dialog.findViewById(R.id.chkbox1)`

Answer (score 0):

I am trying add radio group to the custom dialog .. It comes when dialog is loaded , but how to add the action lister to that radio group in the dialog  .. below is my custom layout xml .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="4dp"

     />


 <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chksmart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SMARTAPPLIANCE    " 

     android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/meter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Device"
     android:layout_below="@+id/chksmart"
     />
 <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/android:list" 
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"  >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioGet"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="radioClickHandler1"
        android:text="GET"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"  />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioPut"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="radioClickHandler1"
        android:text="PUT"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"  />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioPost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="radioClickHandler1"
        android:text="POST"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"  />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioDelete"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="radioClickHandler1"
        android:text="DELETE"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"  />
      <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioevent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="radioClickHandler1"
        android:text="ADDEVENT"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"  />
</RadioGroup>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" SUBMIT "
    android:textColor="#00000f"
    android:textSize="25px"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radiogroup"
    />
```