# Custom Dialog: Reference items in Custom View

Tags: android

I am at a loss as to how to reference an item in a custom dialog. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296174/android-check-box-and-radio-group-on-custom-dialog), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192378/findviewbyid-returns-null-tried-everything), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626006/android-custom-dialog-cant-get-text-from-edittext), and other places. **I cannot get the checkbox in the custom dialog to be referenced in an onclick event, or when I try to call it directly in the positive buttons onClick**.

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/delete_db_on_exit"
    android:textColor="@color/Black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:text="@string/confirm_delete"
    android:textColor="@color/Black" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/confirm_delete_checkbox"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/confirm_delete_checkbox"/>
```

Code in Activity that calls dialog:

```
private LayoutInflater inflator;
private View dialogView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_administration);
    inflator = this.getLayoutInflater();
    dialogView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
}

public void deleteDatabases(View view){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.delete_db_on_exit)
            .setCustomTitle(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm_button_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    if (((CheckBox) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.confirm_delete_checkbox)).isChecked()) { //Never true. No exceptions thrown
                        setDeleteDatabaseOnExit();
                        dialog.cancel();
                        //Navigate back to main activity
                        Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(AdministrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(mainActivityIntent, 1);
                    }
                }
            });

    CheckBox confirmDeleteCheckbox = (CheckBox)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.confirm_delete_checkbox);
    confirmDeleteCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int x = 0;
            x = 1;
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
        .setCustomTitle(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null))
```

to:

```
        .setCustomTitle(dialogView)
```

In your dialog you are creating a new custom_dialog view which also has a checkbox but is not same as the one in `dialogView`. That's why when you check it true the one in dialog set's it self to true but the one in dialogView is still false.

Comment: That seemed to fix the issue! Thanks for that! I have been trying to figure this out for hours